# How to get data from React native FormData Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, multipartform-data

I am working on a react native project. I am using FormData to upload my files and input text.

But in form validation, I need to get the Value from the FormData object.
I tried `formData.get('mykey')` but it gives me an error that gets is not a function.
Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `FormData#getParts`:

```
const field = data.getParts().find(item => item.fieldName === 'key'));
if (field) {
  const value = field.string;
}
```

See [relevant React Native source code for FormData](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/FormData.js#L64-L86).